# Mybatis not open session inside JBOSS by LinkageError

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, mybatis

I'm testing mybatis 3.0.6 with JBOSS 4.3 but I can't open a session.

I installed JBOSS today (on Ubuntu), is empty, only other ear and I put the driver for postgress and the datasource file (xx-ds.xml) inside the server.

I made a very simple ear with maven (2.2)

only three jar inside the lib directory

- mybatis-3.0.6.jar
- ejbinterface-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar (only one interface, not used)
- datajar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar (The mapper of mybatis and it's interface)

The code is only one EJB

```
package com.mycompany.it;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import my.company.it.data.MyMapper;
import my.company.it.data.MyData;

import org.apache.ibatis.io.Resources;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSession;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder;


@WebService
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class MyEndPoint{
private SqlSessionFactory sqlMapper=null;

public int multiply(int num, int num2) {

    System.out.println("1.Begin..");

    if(sqlMapper==null){
        try {
            System.out.println("2. Opening Xml");
            sqlMapper = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(Resources.getResourceAsReader("mybatis/SQLMapConfig.xml"));
            System.out.println("3. End with XML");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(sqlMapper!=null){
        System.out.println("4. Open Session");//The Crash
        SqlSession misession = sqlMapper.openSession();
        try {

            System.out.println("5. GetMapper");
            MyMapper mapper = misession.getMapper(MyMapper.class);
            MyData mydata= new MyData();
            mydata.setId(num);
            mydata.setCampito("XXXXX");
            mapper.insertMyData(mydata);
            System.out.println("Good...");

            //othernum=otherbean.getNumber(3,misession);
        } finally{
            misession.close();  
        }
    }

    return num*num2;
}

}
```

When I invoke the EJB this error happend

```
2011-11-27 21:14:36,160 INFO  [STDOUT] 1.Begin..
2011-11-27 21:14:36,160 INFO  [STDOUT] 2. Opening Xml
2011-11-27 21:14:36,194 INFO  [STDOUT] 3. End with XML
2011-11-27 21:14:36,194 INFO  [STDOUT] 4. Open Session
2011-11-27 21:14:36,200 ERROR [org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS] SOAP request exception
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.getConfiguration()Lorg/apache/ibatis/session/Configuration;" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/mx/loading/UnifiedClassLoader3) of the current class, org/apache/ibatis/session/defaults/DefaultSqlSession, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/mx/loading/UnifiedClassLoader3) for interface org/apache/ibatis/session/SqlSession have different Class objects for the type org/apache/ibatis/session/Configuration used in the signature
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.Ejb3TxPolicy.handleExceptionInOurTx(Ejb3TxPolicy.java:63)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:83)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:191)
```

I don't have any special xml for Jboss, and the application.xml is generated by maven and is very simple too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd">
<application>
   <display-name>earpackage</display-name>
      <module>
         <ejb>ejb3test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
      </module>
</application>
```

I need something more for Ibatis? an special file for JBOSS?

If I shutdown JBOSS, the EJB works and open the session and I can call the ejb many times, but if I redeploy (hot-deploy) the error happens...  need I close something?